# Bijection between Hilbert space and Vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have a real separable infinite dimentional Hilbert space $H_1$ with vectors denoted by $g(x)$. We also have a bijective linear map between $H_1$ and another real vector space $H_2$ (with elements $f(x)$) that perserves linearity.

My goal is to understand the properties of $H_2$, including its inner product and whether or not it is also a Hilbert space:

1. is a bijection that preserves linearity between $H_1$ and $H_2$ enough to prove that $H_2$ is a Hilbert space?
2. is it safe to use the bijection and define the inner product on $H_2$ using the elements of $H_1$: ie the inner product between 2 elements of $H_2$, $f_1(x), f_2(x)$:
   $$ \langle f_1(x),f_2(x)\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_1(x)g_2(x)dx$$ $$g_1(x),g_2(x) \in H_1$$
   $$f_1(x),f_2(x) \in H_2$$

thanks

Comment: But of course writing the elements as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively, does not mean the evaluations $f \mapsto f(x)$ or $g \mapsto g(x)$ have any relation to the Hilbert structure, or to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's enough. Let $S : H_1\to H_2$ be your linear bijection. On $H_2$ you introduce the inner product
$$
\langle f_1,f_2\rangle_2 := \langle S^{-1}f_1,S^{-1}f_2\rangle_1.
$$
Then $(H_2,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_2)$ is a Hilbert space. First of all, $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_2$ is surely bilinear, and it's also positive definite as $\langle f,f\rangle_2 = 0$ implies $S^{-1}f=0$ and thus $f=0$. For the completeness, let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $H_2$. Then $(S^{-1}f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence on $H_1$ and thus converges to some $g\in H_1$. Let $f := Sg\in H_2$. Then $S^{-1}(f_n-f)$ converges to zero in $H_1$ and therefore $\|f_n-f\|_2 = \|S^{-1}(f_n-f)\|_1\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.